# Wrapper for SQL queries

Tags: .net, sql, wrapper

I have one idea to write library for .NET. This library will be object wrapper for SQL queries, this is not ORM, this is easy tool to avoid hardcode SQL in small projects. For example of using:

```
var query = Query.Select("Name")
                 .From("Product")
                 .Where("Price", Operator.MoreThan, 5);
string result = query.Build();
```

in `result` you get generated SQL code:

```
SELECT Name FROM Product WHERE Product.Price > 5
```

Does anybody know similar libraries for .NET ?

Comment: [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

Comment: it works only with object entites. My idea is more similar. In result obtained only string of query.

Comment: How is code like this better than pure SQL?

Comment: insted of harcode string with SQL we can use strong typed language.

Comment: @svick I think this approach would enable compile time or at least runtime checks for the logical structure and provide support against missing whitespace, brackets etc.

Comment: and when you mistype the field in say, Select("Nam"), how will "strong" typing help you? On the outside (JVM) looking in, LINQ is a pretty awesome DSL, imo. I would love to use it, actually looking into Mono now (on Linux, but may bite the bullet and fire up Windows VM and give Visual Studio a test spin)

Comment: @Glum, strong typing makes sense the way LINQ uses it: if you make a typo in the name of the column, the compiler (and the IDE) tells you so. If you just use strings, there is no strong typing.

Comment: @svic, @virtualeyes, I understand that this is not full strong type, and you can mistype in names of tables or columns, but names is the only place you can mitype, and you can use constants for all names. I like L2S too, but this approach gives more access to SQL. For example in L2S you can not doing smth like this:  Query.DeleteFrom("Product").Where("id". Operator.MoreThan 5);

Comment: @Glum but there is a second DSL for that, aka TSQL - `delete from Product where id > 5` - just as "safe" as your version. DataContext allows you to execute commands like that trivially... as does dapper and ado.net

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef) or [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx). It should be noted that EF is seeing much more active development.

Answer (score 0):

iBatis.Net and NHibernate do similar things.